# Has anyone experimented with getting a video played on a mini app? On the Alipay site there is some documentation, still wanted to post the question

Tags: vodapay-miniprogram

Wanted to know if any of you guys have played around with getting a video to play in a mini app? I have looked at some of the Alipay documentation and from what I can see there is only one supported platform to upload a video to in order to use within the mini app...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant get videos to play in native mini programs because the  tag is not currently supported.

You could get videos to play by making use of the web-view which points to a website which hosts the video